# java swagger api code - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'i' in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-codegen

I generated an API code for editor.swagger.com and i was getting following error.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'i'
at java.base/java.text.SimpleDateFormat.compile(SimpleDateFormat.java:849) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.text.SimpleDateFormat.initialize(SimpleDateFormat.java:657) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.text.SimpleDateFormat.(SimpleDateFormat.java:628) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.text.SimpleDateFormat.(SimpleDateFormat.java:603) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizerConfiguration$StandardJackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer.configureDateFormat(JacksonAutoConfiguration.java:277) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.16.RELEASE.jar:2.1.16.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizerConfiguration$StandardJackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer.customize(JacksonAutoConfiguration.java:243) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.16.RELEASE.jar:2.1.16.RELEASE]

Answer (score 0):

i fixed this error by commenting following in application.properties

#spring.jackson.date-format=io.swagger.RFC3339DateFormat